# Cartesian sum of matrices without permuting or reshaping

Tags: matlab, bsxfun

I have two 2d matrices a and b. Let's say `a = randn(10, 20)` and `b = randn(10, 30)`. I want to compute the Cartesian sum! of these two arrays, i.e., each column of a, and each column of b should be selected once, and added together into a matrix c of size (10, 20*30). This can be done by using `bsxfun`, `permute`, and `reshape` as:

```
c = bsxfun(@plus, a, permute(b, [1 3 2]));
c = reshape(c, [size(a,1), size(a,2)*size(b,2)]);
```

I was wondering if there exists a faster more direct way of doing this, without need for permuting or reshaping. I know it is easy to write a mex function for this, but I wonder if mex is necessary.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the most direct approach is the fastest!

```
c = zeros(size(a, 1), size(a, 2) * size(b, 2));
ic = 1;
for ib = 1:size(b, 2)
    for ia = 1:size(a, 2)
        c(:, ic) = a(:, ia) + b(:, ib);
        ic = ic + 1;
    end
end
```

#### Example

```
a = randn(10, 20); 
b = randn(10, 30);

% # Originally proposed method
tic
c1 = bsxfun(@plus, a, permute(b, [1 3 2]));
c1 = reshape(c1, [size(a, 1), size(a, 2) * size(b, 2)]);
toc

% # Method suggested by gevang
tic
[pB, pA] = meshgrid(1:size(b, 2), 1:size(a, 2));
c2 = a(:, pA(:)) + b(:, pB(:));
toc

% # Direct approach
tic
c3 = zeros(size(a, 1), size(a, 2) * size(b, 2));
ic = 1;
for ib = 1:size(b, 2)
    for ia = 1:size(a, 2)
        c3(:, ic) = a(:, ia) + b(:, ib);
        ic = ic + 1;
    end
end
toc
```

and the results are:

```
 Elapsed time is 0.005850 seconds.
 Elapsed time is 0.009442 seconds.
 Elapsed time is 0.000328 seconds.
```

As you can see, a double `for`-loop in this case is almost 20 times faster...

Comment: @EitanT although not the intention of the OP, speed comparisons are always welcomed. My numbers are different though, average times over 10000 trials for those sizes: `1.0e-03*[0.0734,  0.0906, 0.2971] seconds.` Can you please check again, or am I missing something?

Comment: @gevang Surprisingly, both results are correct. After the first trial, the results look like yours! The first and second method suddenly run x100 faster, but I'm not sure what causes the change in performance between trials...

Comment: @EitanT even for a single, first trial, times are on the orders I mentioned, straightforward one is always slower, but with negligible differences among them for those matrix sizes. Now, by by using `a [10 x 2000]` and `b [10 x 3000]` times become `[0.527368, 1.481317, 3.166863] seconds.` To see an actual gain in time you have to increase the 1st dimension of the matrices (i.e >100). So, at the end of the day you might say that time depends on the original sizes of `a` and `b`.

Comment: @gevang For single trials I keep getting consistent time measurements where a straightforward for-loop is faster by more than an order of magnitude... strange.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. With my machine configuration and matlab v 7.14 I consistently get similar or better results for the original solution. For larger matrices the for-loop approach becomes more time consuming though.

Comment: @user1210230 weird, because I've run mine on a high performance DELL server... (tested on much larger matrices too). Then again, you should use the solution which works fastest for you...

Answer (score 0):

You can generate all column index combinations in advance, e.g. using `meshgrid,` then add in parallel the properly indexed matrix values for the`[size(a,1), size(a,2)*size(b,2)]` final matrix of values:

```
a = randn(10, 20); 
b = randn(10, 30);

[pA, pB] = meshgrid(1: size(a,2), 1: size(b,2));
c = a(:, pA(:)) + b(:, pB(:));
```

Comment: I was just about to write the same solution, but it seems that it is actually **slower** than that suggested in the question...